# Seeking clarification "OAuth consumer Id" from docs

Tags: rest-api, oauth2, connected-apps, isv

We are new ISVForce Partners and need to create an Oauth 2 flow in our component to make REST API calls.  I am following the official docs and there is a sentence I don't really understand:

> Partners, who wish to get an OAuth consumer Id for authentication, can contact Salesforce - [Official Documention](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_rest.meta/api_rest/quickstart_oauth.htm)

Could somebody elaborate on what OAuth consumer Id is.  I can't find a definition anywhere online.

Perhaps the OAuth consumer Id is an OAuth token?

Is this a generic token that Partners (us) can use to access the REST API of any of our customer's orgs?  If so, would there be any value in us implementing a  OAuth 2.0 connected app?

Answer (score 2):

We actually faced a similar scenario and I stumbled into the same mysterious line in that document. Unfortunately I went back to Salesforce Support and here is their answer:

> I reached out to product management team and they confirmed that this is a document bug, this information is not correct "Partners, who wish to get an OAuth consumer Id for authentication, can contact Salesforce". For authentication, the connected app is required and a valid Salesforce user with required permissions.

I would only assume Salesforce will eventually delete that "bug" in mentioned document, in case this is found by somebody else in the future and doesn´t understand what we´re talking about.